# Where is the center of space / universe?

Tags: deep-space

Where is the center of universe?

[image: Universe]

There is cosmic microwave background radiation, and there is its Doppler effect. Is there any map with geographical center of universe? What is situated there? How far from us this center?

I found this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Center_of_the_Universe
, but it's like half-mythology theory and no facts/photos.

Comment: [Everywhere is the center of the Universe](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/25592/21740). This question is however off-topic on [space.se] as per [FAQ], and would be better asked on our sister [SE] website [physics.se], if it wasn't already covered by multiple similar questions: [Does the universe have a center?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591/21740), [Does (it make sense to say that ) the universe has a center?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16074/21740), [etc.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=center+of+the+universe).

Comment: It's right here next to me. Viewings are on the hour, from 9 to 5, only $4.

Comment: 2TildalWave, this answer "Everywhere" looks like, center of Solar system is "Everywhere", center of Milky Way is "Everywhere", etc...

Comment: @ramjet The solar system and the Milky Way have human defined boundaries (though they're frequently changing), that gives them a center. The universe is significantly different.

Comment: @Byte56 - I was gonna say that! And we're both right. :)

Comment: 2moders, "This question does not appear to be about space exploration,", center of universe is missing from space exploration?

Comment: That "center of the Universe" that is depicted on the photograph you're attaching is merely a center point of observations made by the [Chandra X-Ray Observatory](http://chandra.harvard.edu/xray_astro/dark_matter/index3.html) (the blue-green dotted image of mapping of dark matter, that's attached to the beginning of the spacetime tunnel). Move the observation point somewhere else, and the "center of the Universe" moves with it. The "zero obvious center" nature of these observations kinda proves it. It's a bit like asking where on the 2D map of the Earth is Earth's center. It's everywhere!

Comment: This is 4D map of Universe, not a 2D. On the 2D map of Earth, center inside. Uderground. Look at this picture https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Earth-crust-cutaway-english.svg, Center of Earth is a middle of shear. I mark by red the 2D image of cosmic microwave background radiation. But it should looks like sphere and center of this sphere lay on the central white line.

Comment: @ramjet - Please read my response again. I was comparing it to searching for a 3D center on a 2D map, not saying in how many dimensions the tunnel is depicted in. I'm not sure how we're ever going to understand each other, if you insist in reading things that were never said. And for what it's worth, and again - there is not a single point on a 2D map of the Earth's surface, that you could say is the center of the Earth. Or, you could say all of the points on the map point towards the center of the Earth, when you project that map onto a sphere.

Comment: Expanding this to that tunnel on the picture, if you make a cross section at any point along its axis, and expand that to a surface of a sphere, you'd get a 4D representation of the Universe on surfaces of those infinite number of spheres. But when you make a cross section, the "center of the Universe" line becomes a dot in 2D, and expanded to 3D still remains a dot, but it could be anywhere on the surface of the sphere, not in it. Thus the [balloon analogy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/47098/21740).

Comment: I read this post, it is partly delirium. Center of the expanding sphere is a point in the 2D model, is a point in the 3D model, but is a line in the 4D model (with time). Furthermore, there is farthest object https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background_radiation it may be taken like a sphere. And look at this part: "The latter is caused by the peculiar velocity of the Earth relative to the comoving cosmic rest frame as the planet moves at some 371 km/s towards the constellation Leo."

Comment: "Center of the expanding sphere is a point in the 2D model, is a point in the 3D model, but is a line in the 4D model (with time)". Yes, with time. Because that cross section we expanded before onto a sphere is but a time slice of that tunnel image. Stack those slices together, and draw a line between the points, and you get what's represented on that tunnel. As for "background radiation", I think the easiest to appreciate what we're discussing here is to apply time to it - i.e. "when was it?" not "where was it". Because it was everywhere, but when you look farther away, you look back in time.

Comment: I literally have no clue what you're going on about any more. Please first read on what background radiation actually is, not just post links to it. You'll soon learn it's more of "when" than "where". It's so distant to us that it is from before galaxies formed. Why? Because the radiation travels at the speed of light, which is finite. It takes for that radiation so long to reach us, it's almost as old as the Universe itself. And as long ago as that, here used to be the same.

Comment: You may find the answer you're looking for (at least partially) [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/does-the-universe-have-a-center). If you'd like to dispute the closure of this question, I suggest posting on the [meta] site to get the community here to chime in with an explanation or some reopen votes.

Answer (score 5):

When you believe in the Big Bang theory, which is the standard theory, the universe started from a singularity. With the Big Bang space evolved. The room itself evolved so you can either say there is no center or the center is anywhere.

The reason there is no background radiation wave that passed from the center over everything else is because there's no such thing as a center. The space evolved and therefore the center. The background radiation is everywhere in the universe.

You can't take a picture of the universe in total.

Comment: Big Bang theory is about Bang going from one tiny point, there is endmost object in the universe, cosmic microwave background radiation, it has spherical shape, sphere has center. Where i'm wrong?

Comment: "... the Big Bang theory, which is the standard theory taught in every school as far as I'm aware ..." I guess that depends on what you mean by school:  In terms of "schools of thought", this currently is easily the most widely accepted scientific theory.  However, in terms of "elmentary school", "middle school", "high school" or "school of higer education", there are schools which teach otherwise, as the big bang theory contradicts other teachings those schools promulgate.

Comment: @GreenMatt I removed the part. It had nothing to do with the answer, anyway.

Comment: Could we point to the geometric middle of the universe though? Point at the night sky and say "there's the middle of everything"?

Comment: @SF. No, because every point in the universe was equally the center. The fabric of space itself expanded. Initially, the universe was very tiny -- not just the part of the universe with mass, the universe as a whole. _This_ fabric of space has expanded. So every point of the universe now is the center.

Comment: @Manishearth: But the universe does have edges. The point equidistant from all the edges is the **geometric** center now, and forget what happened some 15bln years ago and how did the center from back then travel or expand!

Comment: @SF. Except that by that definition there's no fixed center because it would vary from reference frame to reference frame.

Comment: @Manishearth: In its own reference frame? Averaged? Universe expands at roughly the same speed in all directions. Finding the geometric middle applying plain carthesian geometry should be quite doable. Wherever you are, pointing a radiotelescope in one direction will give you "younger" background noise than in another. There must be a point of equilibrium somewhere.

Comment: @SF. Except that this is not Cartesian geometry. And there's no privileged "universe" reference frame. That's what Einstein's work with relativity was all about. You're still thinking classically -- _there is no privileged reference frame_. And averaging won't do anything, you'll get a divergent sum. And the background noise is equal everywhere, more or less.

Comment: 2Manishearth, you are wrong. I point on this in my question. Background noise is not equal everywhere, by this difference was calculated that our Milky Way fly with 371km/s to the constellation Leo. By Einstein's work easily situated center of our Milky Way, it is black hole Sagittarius A. There are no such many problems with plain geometry appear after Einstein. +- one dimension. Point -> Line. Line -> Field.